# overflow hidden to a row class

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have my html page here : https://jsfiddle.net/2ra6eqnr/1/
if you get a inspect element of my page, you might be see the `row` divison. it doesn't have any height..
but if i set the overflow property of row class to hidden value, it problem fixed.
Its a little bit confusing.. Can any body explain this property and how it work ? and in this case, how overflow property give `row` height ?

Comment: You have to clear your float. Have a look at your updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ra6eqnr/2/).

Comment: This called "Block Formatting context". google it

Comment: So its for clearing the float effect ? ( clearfix )